# How to cast a custom React TypeScript element to an HTMLElement?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have an array of custom elements and I want to store a `ref` for all of them so that I can deliberately call `focus()` on one. Is it possible to cast a custom React element to a DOM element which would allow `focus()`?

SampleFeed.tsx

```
class Feed extends React.Component<{ posts: Post[] },{}> {
    private postRefs: Map<number, Post> = new Map<number, Post>();

    render() {
      <div>
         {this.props.posts.map(
          ((post: Post), (index: number)) =>
           <Post
            ref={(element: Post) => this.postRefs.set(index, element)}
            post={post}
          />)
         }
      </div>
    }

    focusTargetElement() {
      // Does not compile, "Property focus does not exist on Post"
      this.postRefs.get(5).focus();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not post source code of the Post component, so i'll use a sample child component rendering input

### Option 1:

Store the element ref in the child component and create public focus() method called from the parent component

```
class Post extends React.PureComponent {

  private ref: HTMLInputElement

  public render() {
    return <input ref={(ref) => this.ref = ref}/>
  }

  public focus() {
    this.ref.focus()
  }

}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/4w0qrmjk37

### Option 2:

Pass callback method to the child component props

```
class Post extends React.PureComponent<{setRef: (ref: HTMLInputElement) => void}> {

  public render() {
    return <input ref={(ref) => this.props.setRef(ref)}/>
  }

}
```

and keep the elements refs in the parent

```
class Feed extends React.Component<{ posts: Post[] },{}> {
    private postRefs: Map<number, HTMLInputElement> = new Map<number, HTMLInputElement>();

    render() {
      <div>
         {this.props.posts.map(
          ((post: Post), (index: number)) =>
           <Post
            setRef={(element: HTMLInputElement) => this.postRefs.set(index, element)}
            post={post}
          />)
         }
      </div>
    }

    focusTargetElement() {
      // Does not compile, "Property focus does not exist on Post"
      this.postRefs.get(5).focus();
    }
}
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/v3o954jvyl

Comment: Ooo that makes sense. Thanks a lot for explaining!